# Debugging in IntelliJ on OSX El Capitan with multiple monitors

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, debug, intellij-idea, osx-el-capitan

When debugging in IntelliJ on multiple monitors, if I set the debug panel as floating and move it to another screen, whenever I click on the floating panel it moves back to the screen that IntelliJ is displayed. This effectively takes away any ability to take advantage of multiple monitors while debugging on IntelliJ. This happens similarly with all panels.

How do I prevent this panel issue? Is it a known bug - I cannot find any reference to this issue.

Comment: On Yosemite everything worked fine ?

Comment: Mac is super evil about multiple monitors - its just simply impossible to use. Ever tryed to have 2-3 projects open on 3 monitors? It is hillarious how bad OS X is when managing multiple windows of same app.

Comment: As of Mountain Lion I believe that multiple monitors is excellent on OSX. My research has led me to a page where JetBrains declared the issue a bug with Java 8 (the problem doesn't exist in 7 or 6).  https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/466722 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-140852

Comment: Turns out the version of the OS doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

From [the link that ktamlyn posted](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140852): There is a partial workaround: Uncheck in mission control "Displays have seperate Spaces" (have to reboot)